# Where to print out flight info on a public holiday in Mexico City when your accommodation won't do it?

Tags: paperwork, public-holidays, proof-of-onward-travel, mexico-city

I've been staying in Colonia Roma / La Condesa area of Mexico City for the past few days, all public holidays for Semana Santa with most things around here closed.

I need to print out my proof of onward travel China where I'm heading early tomorrow morning. I've been asked to show this info twice already on this trip when boarding or at immigration so don't want to take my chances. It would also be nice to print out a boarding pass for my flight into China and my hostel booking for Beijing, since the printouts I had were kept by the Chinese consulate when I applied for my visa.

For some reason this hostel doesn't do printouts for guests. Last time I was here they recommended a *papelería* nearby, but they've been closed the whole time I've been here this time.

Can anybody offer a suggestion where to get my printing done?

Comment: Try another hostel/hotel nearby? For a small fee most would probably help you out and they're definitely open during the holidays.

Comment: Have you tried a hotel? Those with business centers/services might allow you to print, even if you're not a guest. I've stayed in some that even charged guests to use the computer/printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that [Office Depot Mexico](https://www.officedepot.com.mx) is open on public holidays and their closest branch was only 8 minutes walk from my hostel.

I paid 10 pesos for use of a computer for 15 minutes (the minimum time) and then 8 more pesos to print out 7 or 8 pages.

In Mexico, Office Depot's open hours for most branches are:

> Monday to Friday, from 8:00 am to 10.00 pm
>   Saturday and Sunday, from 9:00 am to 10:00 pm

There is a list of branches with different opening times on the company's [FAQ page](https://www.officedepot.com.mx/officedepot/en/faq).